# Can I get an orientationchange even if the app is locked on portrait mode?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have content in an app that is locked on portrait mode. Is there any way to make an html opened in the in-app browser rotate with a device orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are concerned about your `Activity` being destroyed and re-created due to a configuration change.

Rotation is the most common configuration change, but even for an orientation-locked `Activity`, there are many other ways for this destroy/recreate cycle to be triggered. Split-screen multitasking, for instance, will trigger a configuration change. Or your `Activity` could be destroyed to free up system resources if the user puts your app in the background.

Locking the screen orientation will stop orientation changes from happening, but doing so won't magically solve all problems related to `Activity` destruction and recreation.